# How to add total in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

How to add total in ssrs report using ssrs 2005 manually without using a wizard?
I can do it in ssrs 2008 by simply add total and

Additional question: it seems it is hard to group records here in ssrs 2005 i cannot see row groups and column groups.

Answer (score 2):

For a table total, you will need to enable the header and/or footer; you can do this by right clicking on the left side of the table:

[image]

For a group total, you will need to right click the left of the group row and enable headers/footers in the properties:

[image]

[image]

Addressing your second question, you cannot compare the 2005 report items/designer to 2008 and above - there was a major redesign of this in 2008. The List, Table and Matrix controls were merged in 2008 into one underlying Tablix object, and the row/column grouping and the way this was managed was changed accordingly; the Row Groups/Column Groups section in BIDS was introduced in 2008. See [The New Report Designer And Tablix](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/stacia/sql-server-2008-the-new-report-designer-and-tablix/) for some more detail here.